# Как в C использовать, работать с русскими символами в консоли?

Tags: c, символы

Помогите разобраться как заставить консоль или компилятор работать с русскими символами. 
Есть строка на русском str[] = "Привет Мир!"
она печатается как строка все хорошо.

но если например сделать сравнение что str[0] == 'П' сделай что-то, это не срабатывает...
при просто печати printf("%c\n", str[0]); выводятся вопросики....

Система Kali Linux

Comment: Укажите ОС, компилятор и код где не работает.

Comment: Система Kali Linux

Comment: код любой не работает при попытке вывести на экран символ или просто поставить сравнение if(str[0] == Ф) при этом строка = ФФФФ  не работает

Comment: Символ «П» состоит из двух байт — str[0] и str[1] соответственно — utf-8 же. По идее `'П'` должно выкидывать ошибку или предупреждение при компиляции, потому что вы в один char попытались запихнуть два байта, а это невозможно

Comment: Можно переводить в wchar, можно работать как со строками (один русский символ в utf-8 занимает 2 байта, но более корректно определять, сколько байт (1, 2, 3 или 4) занимает конкретный символ в utf-8). Почитайте [man 3 mblen](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mblen)

Comment: попробовал перевести в wchar_t но теперь проблема новая опять вопросики и или просто не печатается. printf печатает русскую строку а wprintf вместо русской строки печатает вопросики ((((

Answer (score 3):

Со строками национальных алфавитов можно работать как с многобайтовыми (UTF8) или как со строками широких символов.

При использовании UTF8 каждый символ строки занимает переменное число байтов, поэтому работать со строкой как с массивом символов нельзя! Для доступа к отдельным символам надо проходить по всей строке, получая длину каждого символа функцией mbrlen:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int mbcompare(const char* pStr, int index, const char* pMatch)
{   
    mbstate_t mbs = { 0 };  
    int len = 0;
    int i = 0;

    const char* pEnd = pStr + strlen(pStr);
    mbrlen(NULL, 0, &mbs);

    while ((len = mbrlen(pStr, pEnd - pStr, &mbs)) > 0)
    {
        if (i == index) {
            return strncmp(pStr, pMatch, len) == 0;
        }
        pStr += len;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}

void mbprint(const char* pStr)
{
    mbstate_t mbs = { 0 };
    int len = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char buf[6];

    const char* pEnd = pStr + strlen(pStr);
    mbrlen(NULL, 0, &mbs);

    while ((len = mbrlen(pStr, pEnd - pStr, &mbs)) > 0)
    {

        strncpy_s(buf,sizeof(buf), pStr, len);
        printf(u8"%2d: %s (%d байт)\n", i,buf,len);

        pStr += len;
        i++;
    }   
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.utf8");    

    char str[] = u8"Привет Мир!";   
    mbprint(str);

    if (mbcompare(str, 1, u8"р")) printf(u8"Символ 1 == [р]\n");
    else printf(u8"Символ 1 != [р]\n");

    getchar();
}

/* Вывод:

 0: П (2 байт)
 1: р (2 байт)
 2: и (2 байт)
 3: в (2 байт)
 4: е (2 байт)
 5: т (2 байт)
 6:   (1 байт)
 7: М (2 байт)
 8: и (2 байт)
 9: р (2 байт)
10: ! (1 байт)
Символ 1 == [р]
*/
```

Выглядит не очень удобно? Возможно, проще будет использовать широкие символы:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU");
wchar_t str[] = L"Привет Мир!";

int c = wcslen(str);
for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
    wprintf(L"%2d: %lc\n", i, str[i]);
}

if (str[1]==L'р') wprintf(L"Символ 1 == [р]\n");
else wprintf(L"Символ 1 != [р]\n\n");
```

Comment: Спасибо )) Похоже на правду )) Я сам новичок )) буду разбираться в коде )) Я сам сейчас как раз пробую через wchar_t только вот нигде не нашел материала что нужно пробежаться по всему массиву int c = wcslen(str);
for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
    wprintf(L"%2d: %c\n",i,str[i]);
} 
Зачем это кстати? Можно чуть подробнее пожалуйста... или где можно почитать...

Comment: ну вот опять ))) повторил код и вот такой результат

0: 
 1: @
 2: 8
 3: 2
 4: 5
 5: B
 6:  
 7: 
 8: 8
 9: @
10: !

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛогинов Исправил, нужно было использовать %lc вместо %с. В Visual C++ работало и так.

Comment: "*Зачем это кстати? Можно чуть подробнее пожалуйста... или где можно почитать*" - Что именно не понятно? Этот код  демонстрирует вывод отдельных символов строки в цикле.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <locale.h>
```

В начале main

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
```

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

Comment: int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
...
return (0);
}

Comment: это все есть, но символы русские все равно не выводятся... Система Kali Linux этот же самый код у товарища на Windows 10 также вопросики... как я понял что русские символы занимают больше места, но как с этим работать? как мне выводить на экран русские символы? В C++ все прекрасно работает ))) В Java тоже )) Почему C не слушается

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛогинов, если вам просто надо вывести сообщение на русском (даже из одного символа), то формируйте его как строку в utf-8 (любимым текстовым редактором) и выводите `printf("%s", "русский текст");` или `fputs("Я", stdout);` (при этом, если терминал работает в utf-8, можно даже не задавать locale)

Comment: да терминал работает в RU-ru.utf-8 как то так... и действительно даже без setlocale русская строка выводится хорошо. но вот символы нет... при этом суть программы в том, чтобы меня символы в строке а в условии идет сравнение русского символа из исходной строки со строкой массива заданного в определенной функции s2[] = "АБВГДЕЖЗИК...ЭЮЯ";
так вот даже сравнение не срабатывает!! как мне проверить то что 1 символ из строки s1[] = "Строка"; т.е. if (s[0] == s2[i]) printf("Найден символ %c", s[0]);